# Appending text onto text file line by line Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, file-handling

I have 2 arrays one of them being song names, and one being artist names, with number 1 in the artist names array being the artist for number 1 in the song names array, and so on. Currently I have put all the song names in a text file, by using a for loop, but i want to put the artist names next to the names of the corresponding songs in the same text file.
Obviously, the code below isnt actual code, but if I want the real code to do something like that. Sorry if this is a confusing question

```
with open('songs.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for x in songnames:
        f.write(x + FOR I IN ARTISTS WRITE I)
```

Comment: Please share some more code. Tell us the content of the files

Comment: As Sujay mentioned, kindly share with us the format in which you have stored the song names in the text file, so that accordingly we can provide a solution to put names of artists next to those song names.

Comment: @SamVarghese What do you mean by the format? The text files are initially empty, but after using the for loop to add the song names (there is not a a specific number of song names, it changes based on user input), there is a song name on each line of the file. I want to add the song artists next to the song names, but don't know how.

Comment: why don't you just write song + artist to file at once? It is easier than write the song first, then append the artist name after.

Comment: @adamkwm because all the songs and all the artists are in 2 different arrays, and I can easily use a for loop and write each element of one of the arrays, but I dont know how I can do both. It would also solve my problem if there was a way to merge arrays element by element for example: input: array1 = [1, 2, 3] array2 = [7, 8, 9] output: array3 = [1 7, 2 8, 3 9]

Comment: If the arrays have corresponding elements, you can use `zip()`; let me write it up as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the arrays have corresponding elements, you can use `zip()`, like this:

```
with open('songs.txt', 'r+') as f:
    for song, artist in zip(songnames, artists):
        f.write("%s: %s\n" % (song, artist))
```

Comment: @Bpython You can also do it by index, `for i in range(len(songs)): f.write(f"{songs[i]} {artists[i]}\n")`.